# No enclosing instance of the type QuestionActivity is accessible in scope[help]

Tags: java, android

Currently doing a quiz app, and having these errors. Tried looking for an answer but nothing helps.

**Practice.java**

```
public class Practice extends Activity {


public static final String QUIZNUM = "QUIZNUM";
public static final int Quiz1 = 1;
public static final int Quiz2 = 2;
public static final int Quiz3 = 3;
public static final int NUMBER_OF_QUESTIONS = 10;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.practice);

    //Menu buttons
    Button quiz1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.q1Btn);
    quiz1.setOnClickListener(new PracticeButton(Quiz1, NUMBER_OF_QUESTIONS));

    Button quiz2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.q2Btn);
    quiz2.setOnClickListener(new PracticeButton(Quiz2, NUMBER_OF_QUESTIONS));

    Button quiz3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.q3Btn);
    quiz3.setOnClickListener(new PracticeButton(Quiz3, NUMBER_OF_QUESTIONS));

}


class PracticeButton implements OnClickListener {

    int quizNum;
    int numQuestions;

    public PracticeButton(int quizNum, int numQuestions){
        this.quizNum = quizNum;
        this.numQuestions = numQuestions;
    }

    public void onClick(View v){


        List<Question> questions = getQuestionSetFromDb();
        CurrentQuiz c = new CurrentQuiz();
        c.setQuestions(questions);
        c.setNumRounds(numQuestions);
        c.setQuizNum(quizNum);

        ((MLearningApp)getApplication()).setCurrentGame(c);

        startActivity(new Intent(QuestionActivity.this, QuestionActivity.class);
    }

}


// Method that retrieves a random set of questions from db

private List<Question> getQuestionSetFromDb() throws Exception {

    DBHelper myDbHelper = new DBHelper(QuestionActivity.this);
    try {
        myDbHelper.createDataBase();
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        throw new Exception("Unable to create database");
    }
    try {
        myDbHelper.openDataBase();
    } catch (SQLException sqle) {
        throw sqle;
    }
    List<Question> questions = myDbHelper.getQuestionSet(quizNum, numQuestions);
    myDbHelper.close();
    return questions;
}
```

}

Getting an error message in

1 - **QuestionActivity.this**    No enclosing instance of the type QuestionActivity is accessible in scope

```
startActivity(new Intent(QuestionActivity.this, QuestionActivity.class);
```

2 - **(QuestionActivity.this)**
No enclosing instance of the type QuestionActivity is accessible in scope

```
DBHelper myDbHelper = new DBHelper(QuestionActivity.this);
```

3 - **(quizNum, numQuestions)**
    - numQuestions cannot be resolved to a 
     variable
    - quizNum cannot be resolved to a 
     variable

```
List<Question> questions = myDbHelper.getQuestionSet(quizNum, numQuestions);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this

```
startActivity(new Intent(QuestionActivity.this, QuestionActivity.class);
```

to

```
startActivity(new Intent(Practice.this, QuestionActivity.class);
```

Read about Explicit intents at

http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html

Change this

```
DBHelper myDbHelper = new DBHelper(QuestionActivity.this);
```

to

```
DBHelper myDbHelper = new DBHelper(Practice.this);
```

For the third

```
int numQuestions; 
//declared in class PracticeButton. not available in  getQuestionSetFromDb().
```

Your `PracticeButton` class ends just before `getQuestionSetFromDb()`.

Move `getQuestionSetFromDb()` inside `PractiveButton` class.

Anyway get hold of tutorial and read the docs.

Comment: It worked. Move the getQuestionSetFromDb() method inside PracticeButton. Thanks a lot!